How to Customize Window Class Name in Avalonia?
I've developed a software application using Avalonia that runs on the Windows operating system. However, the window of this software needs to be captured by another application, which relies on the window title and class name for configuration. Therefore, I need to customize the class name of the window, which is displayed as something like "Avalonia-e0e3c6f1-9942-4902-9230-25331dc796c2" in spy++. In Avalonia, the window class name appears to be randomly generated. Is there any way to modify this class name?
I'm eager to explore any suggestions or insights into how to customize window class names in Avalonia to meet the requirements of external applications.

One possible approach could be to subclass the main window class in Avalonia and override the default behavior for generating the window class name. You can create a custom window class that extends the standard Avalonia window class and provides a method for setting a custom class name.
using Avalonia.Controls;

    public class CustomWindow : Window
    {
        public CustomWindow()
        {
            // Set a custom class name for the window
            ClassName = "MyCustomWindowClassName";
        }
    }

Then, you can use this custom window class in place of the standard Avalonia window class in your application:
var appBuilder = AppBuilder.Configure<App>();
appBuilder.AfterSetup(builder =>
{
    builder.Instance = new CustomWindow();
});
appBuilder.Start<MainWindow>();

